# Angular JS $http does not respond updated data from database

Tags: php, angularjs, caching

I am trying to update a status on database using this function of services

```
obj.post = function(q, object) {  
return $http.post(serviceBase + q, object).then(function(results) {
            return results.data;
    });
}
```

My query is working fine and data is updated on database but, after getting success message, when I try to get this row again from database using the same service function, my result shows that the status has not been update.

Comment: This question is not very clear. What do you mean by _'when I try to get this row again from the database using the same service(s) function'?_ Note that `$http.get()` and `$http.post()` operate differently but you did not clarify that in your code. Also it is not clear what you what you want to archive when you return a success message and want to get the update model at the same time. The possibilities are many. please add more info to guide visitors. Thanks.

Comment: I solved my problem to add a random number at the end of url as a query string at the end of url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this, 
Use $q service in angular to return a promise which will eventually get resolved with results.data

```
obj.post = function(q, object) {  
    $http.post(serviceBase + q, object).then(function(results) {
        return $q.resolve(results.data);
    });
}
```

Earlier you were directly returning the data , which might not be available 
immediately. So you should return a promise instead

Or, you can just do this ,

```
obj.post = function(q, object) {  
    return $http.post(serviceBase + q, object)     
}
```

this will return a do post and return a promise.